# How to downgrade requirement to glibcxx 3.4.20 of my dynamic library?

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, centos7, libstdc++

I used to build my dynamic library for Centos7 in Docker and everything worked until something happened (or I changed something) and now the .so requires libstdc++ with glibcxx 3.4.20. How to downgrade the requirement? Thanks!

Note that:

- I don't need to supply libstdc++ with the library
- I can't install new packages
- I don't need to update LD_LIBRARY_PATH as suggested in many posts
- I can't upgrade GCC or link stdc++ statically

I only need to know why it got upgraded and how to get it back.

upd:
If I do objdump, I get following symbol:

```
[root@a0d062ba3109 bin]# objdump -x ../plugin/va/lib/libvaplugin.so |    grep GLIBCXX_3.4.20
...
_ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz@@GLIBCXX_3.4.20
```

It looks like throw_out_of_range_fmt is used by vector::range_check. But why it started using it and didn't use throw_out_of_range_fmt before?

Comment: If you need a dependency on an older library version, then build your code on a system with that older version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why it started using it and didn't use throw_out_of_range_fmt before?

You started to use some feature that you didn't use before. Guesses:

1. You enabled exceptions and they were disabled before or,
2. You are now calling `std::vector::at` that you didn't call before.

You can find out *exactly* where the reference to `_ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz` is coming from by adding `-Wl,-y,_ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz` to the link line for your library. That will tell you which `.o` in your library needs the symbol.

Use `objdump -dr foo.o` to look for reference to the symbol, and you'll know which of your functions is calling it.

As Jesper Juhi commented already, if you need you library to work with pre-GCC-4.9 `libstdc++`, you should build it with pre-GCC-4.9 compiler.